# Is it normal that YARD doesn't replace `code` with <code>code</code>?

Tags: ruby, markup, rdoc, yard

I'm just starting to use YARD for documenting my Rails app. I didn't specify any specific Markup handler, but I would have expected that `code` would be converted to `code`, which doesn't seem to happen. Is this normal behavior? Do I have to add some additional option to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

The syntax is a little different from markdown (markdown vs rdoc) I suppose. Using `'+'` works. +code+ gets rendered in a `<code>` block.

Answer (score 21):

From GitHub, I was used to use backticks for inline code comments. So after some research I found the following, very nice solution.

- Add the `redcarpet` gem to your Gemfile
- Run `bundle` command
- Add `--markup=markdown` to your `.yardopts` file
- Start YARD server using `yard server --reload`
- Open localhost:8808 in your browser

Now you can use Syntax like on GitHub, e.g.

````
```ruby
def bla; puts 'bla'; end
```
````

Or

```
`this is inline code`
```

Nice! :)

Comment: You can do the same while creating the docs itself: `yardoc --markup=markdown|textile|rdoc(default) /path/to/sourcefile` Works both ways

Comment: Note that http://rubydoc.info/ uses .yardopts for configuration too, if your project contains it and you need custom options for your project.

Comment: You can also leave the default markup (`rdoc`) for all source files and then override it on a per-file basis. So you can add the `markdown` markup to the `README.md` file, [as described at the end of this section in official docs](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#adding-meta-data-to-extra-files)

Answer (score 9):

Without markdown, YARD will display a code block for an indented line, e.g.

```
  # This is a useful POSIX regex:
  #   [[:lower:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{3}[[:lower:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{4}
```

Two spaces of indent seem to be sufficient.